# How to setup ROCm on MacBook Pro 16in for tensor flow on AMD GPU?

Tags: macos, tensorflow, machine-learning, gpu, amd-processor

I have been using alternate solutions for machine learning on my MacBook, such as google collaboratory. Still, I always faced issues and feel that having the ability to train the models on my MacBook would be of great help.

I came across ROCm, and I believe it might help me use tensorflow-gpu on my AMD GPU. But, the requirements and OS do not match for me. Can you guide me on how to solve this problem?

With regards to specification, I have a 6-Core Intel Core i7, with AMD Radeon Pro 5300M

I would appreciate any other approaches to solve the problem too.